# Connect to internet through DC with 2 network interfaces

Tags: domain-controller, bridge

I have a network like this :

```
Client 1 <== Wireless ==> Access Point <== Wire ==> DC <== Wireless ==> ADSL Modem
```

Client 1 :

```
IP : 192.168.1.181
DG : 192.168.1.100
DNS : 192.168.1.100
```

Access Point :

```
IP : 192.168.1.10
DG : 192.168.1.100
```

DC :

```
IP : 192.168.1.100
DG : 192.168.1.1
DNS : 127.0.0.1
```

ADSL Modem :

```
IP : 192.168.1.1
```

I can ping yahoo.com from client1, but cannot browse the internet. 
**UPDATE1** : my DC has two network interfaces that I bridge together.

**UPDATE2** : I powered down the DC firewall

**UPDATE3** : I set a forwarder for my DC to 8.8.8.8 (Google dns)

Answer (score 5):

By DC, i assume you mean Domain Controller? If so, you are doing it wrong. The DC should handle your DNS, but not be a gateway. Put a proper router into your network topology.

> Internet > ADSL modem > Router/firewall/gateway device > Switch > Servers/clients/access points/etc

Comment: Which gateway and DC I should install kerio on it ?!!

Comment: What Kerio product?

Answer (score 1):

Since all your machines are numbered in the same subnet, you are bridging. But you cannot bridge to a WiFi client connection (that's why WDS has to be enabled on both sides). If the DC is connected to the ADSL modem by wireless as a client, it cannot bridge to additional machines on the same network.

WiFi is *not* wireless Ethernet. It's its own protocol with its own rules. You can't treat a client link to an access point like a wired connection. Unfortunately, WiFi is enough like Ethernet that it's easy to think it's a drop in replacement for a wired link. It is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS is wrongly configured on the DC it should be 127.0.0.1 pointing to itself as the DNS server

Comment: I update my question , It is a syntax mistake .sorry about that

Comment: Do you know on witch gateway and DC I should install kerio on it ?!